# Error when writing a class extending View in android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to xamarin. I have created a demo in xamarin Android. While trying to write a class extending the View class I got an error that the View does not have default constructor. But I have not writted default constructor at all. All I have done is written a class extending the view with a constructor with an argument context which is correct in Android. CAn anyone help me i
[image]

Error Details:
d:Xamarin\AndroidDemo\CustomWrapper.cs(10,10): Error CS1729: 'Android.Views.View' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments (CS1729) (AndroidDemo.Android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to call the super constructor. In java it is just `super(context);`. It should be

```
 public CustomWrapper(Context context) : base(context) {

 }
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot a very basic thing and searching for something else.

Comment: @Harikrishnan Can you validate the answer so others know this problem is solved please?